# Multiple selectors returned when testing text() nodes

Tags: xpath

I am very new to this and need help.

I have HTML block as follows

```
<div class="content-tab content full">
   <h3 class="name">
        Article post to abuse8 17270
   </h3>
   <div class="content">
        AbusedArticlePostPossiblyAbusiveDeny<div style="clear:both;"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

for the xpath I used :

```
//div[@class='content-tab content full']//h3[contains(text(), contentText)]
```

or

```
//div[@class='content-tab content full']//h3[contains(text(), contentText)][1]
```

or

```
//div[@class='content-tab content full']//h3[contains(text(), contentText)]//following-sibling::div[contains(text(),  contentText)]
```

or

```
//div[@class='content-tab content full']//h3[contains(text(), contentText)]//following-sibling::div[contains(text(),  contentText)][1]
```

but it continues to return multiple nodes. I need an output of just single node.

Comment: **[Please do not upload images of input/code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)** The html can be copied as well with right click -> copy as outerHTML in (Firefox|Chrome) Dev Tools (Elements tabs).

Comment: Thanks to add **expected output** clearly in your post

Comment: Please take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks) I've done it for you this time.

Answer (score 0):

This XPath:

```
'//div/h3[@class="name"]/text()'
```

```
" Article post to abuse8 17270 "
```

Test:

```
cat /tmp/file.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=0">
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="content-tab content full">
            <h3 class="name">
                    Article post to abuse8 17270
            </h3>
            <div class="content">
                    AbusedArticlePostPossiblyAbusiveDeny<div style="clear:both;"></div>
            </div>
          </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Open the page in the browser:

```
firefox file:///tmp/file.html
```

Then

In (Firefox|Chrome) Dev Tools, then in `console` tab, type:

```
$x('//div/h3[@class="name"]/text()')[0]
```

```
" Article post to abuse8 17270 "
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt work for me. I got 0 element matching, FYI.. you had an extra ) after text()

Comment: XPath edited, with your edit, now we can test

Comment: I am getting 0 elements matching and undefined output.

Comment: Possibly, you have an `iframe`. This XPath is valid

Comment: Thank you! The tool I am using is ChroPath.  Your XPath is valid but Its extracts the description and not the title. Sorry, I should of been more clear.

Comment: Post edited accordingly. For the future, thanks to add all required informations since the beginning and format your code as well.